# Fastest way to remove all multiple occurrence items from a list?

Tags: python

What is the fastest way to remove all multiple occurrence items from a list of arbitrary items (in my example a list of lists)? In the result, only items that occur a single time in the list should show up, thus removing all duplicates.

input: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 2]]

output: [[1, 3], ]

This solution was slow:

```
output = [item for item in input if input.count(item)==1]
```

This solution was faster:

```
duplicates = []
output = []
for item in input:
    if not item in duplicates:
        if item in output:
            output.remove(item)
            duplicates.append(item)
        else:
           output.append(item)
```

Is there any better solution, probably by first sorting the list? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't care about preserving ordering:

```
from collections import Counter

def only_uniques(seq):
    return [k for k,n in Counter(seq).iteritems() if n == 1]
```

If you do care about preserving ordering:

```
from collections import Counter

def only_uniques_ordered(seq):
    counts = Counter(seq)
    return [k for k in seq if counts[k] == 1]
```

Both algorithms run in `O(n)` time.

---

**Edit:** Forgot you had a list of lists. In order to be able to hash a sequence, it needs to be immutable, so you could do something like this:

```
list_of_tuples = [tuple(k) for k in list_of_lists]
```

And then run `list_of_tuples` through one of the above functions instead. Note that you'll get a list of tuples back out of it - but unless you specifically are modifying the sequences again after this, tuples should work just as well for your purposes.

If you *do* need to convert back, it's pretty much the same:

```
list_of_lists = [list(k) for k in list_of_tuples]
```

Comment: This solutions gives this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I initially missed that you had a list of lists. The main issue here is that lists aren't hashable because they're mutable - if you had instead, say, a list of *tuples*, that would work fine. I've edited in an example way to convert to tuples before running through.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine and is in the magnitude of 100 faster than my initial solution. Before I accept your answer, however, let's see if someone can beat that solution in speed?

Comment: Sure, though also keep in mind that there's value in keeping the code straightforward, which I hope you'll agree this code is. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 2]]
print list(set(tuple(i) for i in a))
```

Above one liner does the job.

user$ time python foo.py
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]

real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m0.010s

For printing only unique items as asked by Questioner. Solution is a variant of Amber's solution except that I am not using collections module.

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 2]]
d = {tuple(i): a.count(i) for i in a}
print [k for k, v in d.iteritems() if v == 1]
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: That is not what the OP was asking for... compare your output to the sample output provided by the OP.

Comment: Amber is right, this solution does not match the desired output.

Comment: (1) After you've called `set`, you can't claim you're preserving order.  (2) Calling `a.count(i)` for each `i` in `a` will be very, very slow for large `a`.

Comment: Thanks DSM. I was wrong in that part. Have corrected the sentence.

Comment: Also, your second approach will only give *one* element which has no duplicates, even if there are several; fixing that will recover a variant of Amber's solution.

Comment: @DSM Thanks again for correcting! I was a bit careless. I have fixed the code.